# then() for Q.all() not being called

Tags: node.js, q, deferred

In Node.js, I am waiting for several requests to finish before I make a function call as follows:

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    for(var s in symbols){
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var url = rootURL;
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                    deferred.resolve();
                    console.log("resolved");
            }
        });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```

I am waiting for all the requests as follows

```
loadQuotes(symbols.slice(0,3)).then(function(data){
    console.log("done");
    httpServer();
}).done();
```

All of the requests are made, but I do not see "done" printed to the console. The `promises` variable is indeed a list of promises, and they have all been "resolved", yet the `then` function is not called. Any ideas?

Comment: `for (var s in symbols)`? You don't use `s` anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: I use it in the url, I left that portion out

Comment: You are also not handling the error case in your request callback (preferably by calling `deferred.reject(error)`) so if an error occurs your promises will never resolve.

Comment: all of the deferred resolves, the appropriate number of "resolved" is printed out

Comment: @Abundance are you stuck using ES5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scoping problem.  Your variable `deferred` is local to your whole function, not just to the `for` loop so you are overwriting that variable in your loop before you use it in the callback and thus you don't resolve all the deferred objects you created.  Remember the callback happens sometime later after the `for` loop has fully run its course.

A simple fix would be to change to use `let` instead of `var`.  That will make your `deferred` variable local to the `for` loop scope rather than the whole function scope.

But, my preferred fix would be to make a promisified version of `request()` that returns a promise and use that.

```
function rp(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, response, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) reject(new Error(response.statusCode));
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

Then, you can just use that:

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    for(var s in symbols){
        var url = rootURL;
        promises.push(rp(url));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Or, if you really need to use the Q library still, you could write the above code using that too.

FYI, there is a `request-promise` library that returns a promise that is a substitute for the `request` library.  You could use that too.

---

Note, assuming `symbols` is an array and you want to stick with an ES5 solution, you could also just switch your `for` loop to use `.forEach()` and that would create a new function scope for each invocation of the loop, also solving your issue.

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    symbols.forEach(function(s) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var url = rootURL;
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                deferred.resolve(info);
                console.log("resolved");
            }
        });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    });
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.

Comment: Gah, forgot to mention `forEach()`... the most practical ES5 pattern to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

## `var` does not use lexical scoping

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    for(var s in symbols){
        // here you declare `deferred` using `var`
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var url = rootURL;
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                // this is called *later*
                // when it is overwritten
                // with the last value
                // for every iteration
                deferred.resolve();
                console.log("resolved");
            }
        });
        // here, you expect it to be resolved later
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```

So basically, you have an array of pending promises you're waiting on, in which only the last one is ever resolved, because the rest of them were lost in the scope.

### Solution

- ES6 `let` to the rescue

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    for(var s in symbols){
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        var url = rootURL;
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                deferred.resolve();
                console.log("resolved");
            }
        });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```

- `.bind()` your anonymous callback function

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    for(var s in symbols){
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var url = rootURL;
        request(url, function (deferred, error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                deferred.resolve();
                console.log("resolved");
            }
        }.bind(null, deferred));
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```

### Addendum

[As was pointed out by @Karl-Johan Sjögren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854762/then-for-q-all-not-being-called/44854917#comment76690476_44854762), you need to `deferred.reject(error)` in your callback when there is an error, otherwise the `Q.all()` will never settle, and your application will hang whenever there's a problem, rather than responding gracefully.

To be clear, I'm not saying that contributed to the problem here, but that it will create a problem if you don't do that. So to summarize:

```
function loadQuotes(symbols){
    var promises = [];
    for(var s in symbols){
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var url = rootURL;
        request(url, function (deferred, error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                // pass something meaningful here
                deferred.resolve(info);
                console.log("resolved");
            } else {
                // always reject errors when they occur
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        }.bind(null, deferred));
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```